# Not validating POST variables before sending to PayPal - when to check?

Tags: php, post, paypal, paypal-ipn

We have a PHP system on which we're using Micah Carrick's "PHP Paypal IPN Integration Class" (http://www.micahcarrick.com/php-paypal-ipn-integration-class.html).

In his sample code, he recommends that we verify POST variables before passing them onto PayPal

```
switch ($_GET['action']) {

   case 'process':      // Process and order...

... 
      // This is where you would have your form validation  and all that jazz.
      // You would take your POST vars and load them into the class like below,
      // only using the POST values instead of constant string expressions.
      // For example, after ensureing all the POST variables from your custom
      // order form are valid, you might have:
      //
      // $p->add_field('first_name', $_POST['first_name']);
      // $p->add_field('last_name', $_POST['last_name']);

... 
    $custom=$_SESSION['sess_user_id']."~".$_POST['promo_code'];
    $p->add_field('user_id', $_SESSION['sess_user_id']);
    $p->add_field('custom', $custom);
    $p->add_field('amount', $_POST['amount']);
...
    $p->submit_paypal_post(); // submit the fields to paypal
      break;
```

However, we're not doing that for the variables mentioned above.

Should we verify at (a) this stage or at the stage that PayPal (b) returns the data or both?

How should we be verifying the data as well?

Comment: @Lucanos, @Matt Asbury, @thedev - Is there a standardized / systematic way of storing the information at the backend and "holding it" for comparison?

Comment: It's a wonderful thing called a "database". (Sorry man, just too easy.) But, seriously, you should be using a database (MySQL, SQLite, etc.), if you are processing payments - recording what you are selling, how much it costs, who you are selling it to, and whether the payment was cleared via PayPal.

Comment: of course, but should i hold all fields, or a hash / checksum, what should i keep track of as the paypal identifier and when i get the results back how should i handle concurrency issues that may arise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should Validate and Verify your data at both ends - before you send the user off to PayPal, and when you recieve the PayPal IPN Message confirming the payment.

Validation Before ensures that the user is paying the correct amount, that they are being sent to the correct PayPal Account, and you have an identifier against the transation (in the "custom" variable) to allow you to marry the payment against the correct user/purchase when it is confirmed by PayPal.

Validation After ensures that, again, the correct amount has been paid, the transaction identifier is present, valid and correct, and the user/purchase is updated to reflect the transation result.

Comment: Your original code above, for example, takes the amount value from a POST Variable. What if someone hijacked your form handler and modified the POST Variable to be "0.01"? Your code, or what we see of it, would not detect this and would pass the transaction over to PayPal for processing and confirmation. It is not secure.

Comment: I understand the validation before passing to PayPal, but why after? If I add some code that validates that indeed the call is coming from PayPal, is it okay if I blindly accept whatever is coming from there?

Comment: @matt74tm: Blindly trusting any input is the first step on the very short track to failure. When I send a user off to Paypal to make a payment, I make sure the data I am sending to Paypal is accurate (the prices, etc.), but when I recieve the IPN Message back from Paypal, I need to check the transaction ID, the amount paid, how much should have been paid and also perform the IPN Verfication with Paypal to ensure that it is legitimate. For a small investment in time and energy, the confidence that the transaction is as expected is well worth it. Anything else is easily spoofed/faked.

Answer (score 1):

You should verify them before they are sent to PayPal. You should check for things like empty variables, the type is correct (amount shouldn't contain letters for example), the amount of characters (if applicable) is correct. Basically the fields should reflect what you would expect to find in there.

Comment: (a) shouldnt I be checking the values themselves? (b) is this check sufficient or should I be checking when I get things back as well?

Comment: Sorry I meant the actual values in the variables should be checked. And it couldn't hurt to check the results you get back from PayPal as well.

Comment: not sure why on the return that is necessary (see thread with Lucanos)

Comment: @matt74tm: It's just as a double check really. What if PayPal change the API or part of the data is lost in transmission. You would hope that these are unlikely occurrences but you should try and protect against every conceivable situation.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is in both cases.

Validation before sending the data is mandatory.

On response, I think it is a good thing to do.